# Is there an equivalence to ControlPlance for Mac?

Tags: software-recommendation, automation

Looking for a counterpart to [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/about/) that I run on OS X!

ControlPlane is a GUI for setting up custom actions in certain "contexts". A context could be a certain SSID, a specific USB peripheral, a running application and so on.

Does such thing exist for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Found what seems to be the perfect match: [Cuttlefish](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cuttlefish/) (thanks to [OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/09/automate-ubuntu-with-cuttlefish))

Not as refined as ControlPlane, but likely a good equivalent regardless.

[image: Cuttlefish screenshot]